# Recon events are not generated for trusted reconciliation

Tags: event-handling, scheduled-tasks, oim, trusted

After running scheduler recon events are not generated but the status of scheduler shows "success"
Log shows the below error :

```
ORACLE.IAM.CONNECTORS.ICFCOMMON.RECON.SEARCHRECONTASK  oracle.iam.connectors.icfcommon.recon.SearchReconTask : handle : Recon event skipped
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

I havent using any attributes which is of type Boolean

Comment: Which connector are you using? was it working earlier?